# How to kill Prototype's final boss?

Tags: prototype

How do I kill the Supreme Hunter in Prototype?

Comment: This question does not really seem to have enough information in it. Unless this is something anyone who has finished the game immediately gets, and if so you should really add the "spoiler" tag to it.

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming normal difficulty:*

Run around the deck whittling away at him with the whipfist. Whipfist can also be helpful to longshot grab a soldier to consume, but generally dash-grabbing does the trick. Keep your health high, and make sure to avoid his tentacle barrage. Your priority should be to remain at decently high health -- after that, see what you can do about doing a bit of damage. Let the military do most of the damage for you. If you're maxed out on health, give him a bit o' the ol' critical pain devastator.

In general, I kept moving and usually airborne. Stay at max whipfist range while airdashing/gliding to dodge when necessary. If you take a hit or two, feel free to speed your way to the opposite side of the carrier while you rest up and dine on marines. Don't bother with air attacks (whipfist excepted), as he will just block them.

When he hits (I believe) 30%, you'll get a counter and you'll have about three minutes to finish. A couple critical pains at this point should be enough to finish him -- this in mind, as he nears 30%, make sure your health is capped and don't use any devastators. You don't want to use one right before the timer starts and then not have enough juice to finish. There will still be a few stray soldiers to consume if you need, but not as plentiful as before. Wait for the timer to come up and unload on him.

If you didn't have enough to kill him, you have a few options: if he's very close to death, you may still be able to finish him off with the whipfist while maintaining safe distance. If there's anything left on the flight deck to throw, that can do a bit more damage. Last (riskier) option is to let him smack you around to give you an adrenaline surge, and give a last critical pain to finish him. I personally was able to finish him just on the critical pains from the health I had when the timer started.

Comment: I am playing on normal difficulty. And, by the time I am about to kill him, the time gets up. I have been fighting him for almost last 24 hours.

Comment: So the main issue is killing him quickly when you get to the timed portion, not surviving until you get there. Are you able to get clean critical pain devastators off on him, or is he interrupting you and dropping your health before you get to him?

Comment: i don't get to drop the devastators. i later fixed to only muscle mass strategy and killed him anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're on Normal difficulty.

> One way to win this fight is to let yourself almost get killed with the regeneration upgrade equipped in order to use a devastator attack and stun the boss, then bash on him for a while and go in for the grab attack. When he throws you off, run around and heal while chipping away at his health with various guns/the military. Eventually the countdown for the nuclear bomb to explode will begin and you'll be forced to kill him in good time, so get your health low again and use another devestator attack to...well, devastate your opponent's health. Beat on him some more and the battle's yours. This is shown in [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KA86KqMOXjY&feature=related). Another way to handle the first part of the fight, before the bomb, is simply to run around and avoid attacks. The military does gradually take away the Hunter's health, and they never stop spawning, so you can let them do the dirty work while you jump around.